# Updating from Joomla 1.5.20 to most secure release

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, updates

I'm updating a Joomla page for a friend of mine - and the version currently online (when it's not being brought down by hackers) is 1.5.20. As far as I can see, there are [no update patches available](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=index) to bring this up to date. I'm aware that I can't update this to a 2.x or a 3.x version, but if I at least could bring this up to the newest version of the 1.5.x releases, that'd be good for security.

So, what patch should I choose, and where can I find it?

Comment: Your assumption that updating to the currect 1.5 realease will be 'good for security' is flawed. The last patch for 1.5 was on 27.03.12, nearly a year ago. J1.5 has no support because it has come to the end of it's life, it is not because it is now secure and doesn't need patches.

Comment: Fully aware of this @seavers. However, my buddy / client simply wants to "buy some time" before updating to another CMS altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.5_from_an_existing_1.5x_version);

> - If you are on the version prior to the current one, use the file that updates from the prior version to the current version (for example, [Joomla_1.5.25_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73387/Joomla_1.5.25_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.zip)).
> - If you are on an older version, use the 1.5.0 to current version file (for example, [Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73384/Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.zip)).

In your case, since you currently have 1.5.20 and 1.5.26 is the latest 1.5.x version released, the latter would be the correct choice.

Further update instructions are at the above linked docs, read them first, esp. when it comes to backing up the existing site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no patch to upgrade from any Joomla 1.5 version to the current release.

The current Long Term Release (LTR) is Joomla 2.5, the lastest Short Term Release (STR) is Joomla 3.0.

Both of these are not directly upgradeable from any 1.5 version.

Your best bet would be to migrate using a tool such as:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609

Please note that Joomla 1.5 is now unsupported, with no security patches issued to fix any vulnerabilities. Your Joomla 1.5 install will be getting unsecure, very quickly.

As Joachim said, backup first, restore at your leisure.